# Which version of split supports flag -p?

Tags: split, portability

This command does not work in GNU Coreutils split, split of Cern Linux 5 (Redhat) and BSD (Apple Yosemite 10.10.3):

```
split -p'\0' input.txt
```

where input.txt is `masi\0hello\0world`. 
Some comments about the versions follow:

- I do `split -p'\0' input.txt` in BSD Split but I get nothing as output in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14).
- I do `echo 'masi\0hello' | split -p'\\0'` in split 5.97 GNU 2012 in CERN Linux 5 (Redhat). Output `split: unrecognized option --p\\0'`.
- no option -p in GNU Coreutils split

I have forgot where I successfully used the option `-p` with `split`. 
Which version of `split` *does* support the flag `-p`?

Comment: `\0` is literal string or `NULL` byte?

Comment: `-p` see pattern as extended regex, you can try `-p'\\0'`.

Comment: What shell did you use? Redhat won't work, `split` from GNU coreutils doesn't have `-p` option.

Comment: @cuonglm I have tried Split in CERN Linux 5 (which I think is GNU from Freeman), BSD Split and GNU Split from coreutils. Updated the pieces of information in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p` option in Mac OS X will split when a line matches `\0`.  So you need to provide newlines around the `\0`.  Sorry I don't have a solution for you.  You are using the tool wrong.  You might look into perl.  Translate your NUL characters to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, add the newlines and then use split with `-p'^A'` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>).  For example, you can do something like:

```
cat input.txt |perl -p -e 's/\0/\n^A\n/g'| split -p ^A
```

Where `^A` is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, but I'm not sure that matters.